# Graetz diode bridge with series LC circuit oscillation problem

Tags: diodes, zener, bridge-rectifier, oscillation, step-response

I am trying to understand a problem I have encountered. I simulated the voltages on a Graetz diode bridge with a step voltage input of 24 volts. The schematic and the voltage signals are given below. Note that I have color paired the terminals and signals hoping it will help.

[image]

[image]

I have also simulated the voltage and current of a capacitor in a series LC circuit. The input voltage is also a 24 volt step signal. The schematic and signals are given below.

[image]

[image]

When I attached the same LC circuit to the Graetz diode bridge I noticed voltage oscillations at the Graetz bridge output terminals. I also found out that the voltage and current of the capacitor are also oscillating in a manner I do not understand. The schematic and signals are given below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Can somebody please be kind enough to explain to me why this happens? If the diodes were ideal (lets say modeled like a short circuit with a voltage drop of 0.2 volts), I am guessing that there would be no oscillations, is that correct? On the internet I found out that a Zener diode (parallel to the capacitor) is used to stabilize the voltage of such a circuit, but I still don't understand why the oscillations happen in the first place. Thank you for your time.

Comment: So, you are wondering why, when you attach a highly resonant tuned circuit to a previously stable circuit, you get oscillations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

It's easier to see if you set the minimum time step to a much lower value like 10ns.

When power is applied, the diodes conduct and the LC circuit does a half-cycle oscillation, until the inductor current reverses. When it does, the diodes block, after their recovery time, so they keep conducting for a little while and inductor current goes negative. When they finally block, the inductor current has nowhere to go, so its voltage rises until the diodes conduct in reverse, which appears to be around 2000V... and the oscillations continue, with the diodes conducting both in forward and in reverse, until energy is exhausted.

If the diode had zero recovery time, this wouldn't happen, here for example with Schottky diodes:

[image]

It still oscillates but this has more to do with the diode capacitance resonating with the inductor.

Or you can use a snubber:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much bobflux.

Answer (score 1):

And better not use ltspice for that kind of simulation. I think osciloscope would be sfficient here, because simulations seems to fail badly at this stage, and they fail in many programs across, so don't bother looking for anything that works in every exception (well, simple induction shouldn't be an exception but it fails badly)
.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because that coil would fry something, that circuit is missing if i remember correctly few diodes(2). Huge amount of current is released by coil.

Comment: Can you expand this answer?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).